# Where to test IdP-Initiated SSO?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

We've developed a SAML2 SP (supporting IdP-Initiated SSO, as per the user journey we want).

My question is, short of developing an IdP, how can we test it is working? Is there an IdP-Initiated SSO test harness out there? (I know of SSO Circle, but that is for SP-Initiated SSO).

Comment: Didn't get your question? Do you want to develop SAML IdP server or Do you need to test SAML IdP-Init SSO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [trial account](https://www.onelogin.com/free-trial) from Onelogin and configure a [SAML Test Connector](https://onelogin.service-now.com/support), or deploy your own IdP with [simpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp)

Answer (score 0):

You can test out IdP-Initiated SSO via this JS Bin: https://output.jsbin.com/nukiso

```
The code is quite long and wouldn't be appropriate to put directly into this post.
```

It works completely on the browser side and uses web crypto APIs for signing the assertion. It is probably a better idea to use a real IdP as this is more of a tool for learning how to make the SAML response/assertion. To prevent anyone from being able to log into your website without authentication, do not use the JS Bin IdP metadata on a public/production server.